Complex projective n space
In Hatcher chapter $0$, he talks about the construction of CW complex of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ where he says:

The vectors in $S^{2n+1} \subset \mathbb{C}P^{n+1}$ with last coordinate real and nonnegative are precisely the vectors of the form
$$
\Bigl(w, \sqrt{1 - |w|^2}\,\Bigr) \in \mathbb{C}^n\! \times \mathbb{C}
$$
with $|w| \leq 1$. This is a disk $D^{2n}_+$ bounded by the sphere $S^{2n-1} \subset S^{2n+1}$ consisting of vectors $(w, 0) \in \mathbb{C}^n\! \times \mathbb{C}$ with $|w| \leq 1$.

I am not sure why it is $D^{2n}_+$. Does the $+$ sign just show the last coordinate of $\smash{\Bigl(w, \sqrt{1 - |w|^2}\,\Bigr)}$ is nonnegative?

Yes, the upper half-disk.

Before the sentence beginning with "This is a disk ..." you omitted the sentence

Such vectors form the graph of the function $w \mapsto \sqrt{1 -\lvert w \rvert^2}$.

This map is defined on $D^{2n} \subset \mathbb C^n$. More precisely, Hatcher understands it as the map
$$D^{2n} \to \mathbb C, w \mapsto  \sqrt{1 -\lvert w \rvert^2} .$$
It is well-known that the graph $G(f) = \{ (x,f(x)) \mid x \in X \} \subset X \times Y$ of any map $f : X \to Y$ is homeomorphic to $X$ (see e.g. my answer to Subspace topology and homeomorphic mapping). Thus the graph $G$ of the above map is automatically a disk and one can denote it by $D^{2n}_+$ or anything else.
However, the reason for this choice of notation is exactly what you suspect. Actually the graph $G$ is the subset of $S^{2n+1} \subset D^{2n} \times \mathbb C \subset \mathbb  C^{n+1}$ with last coordinate real and nonnegative. In other words, $G = S^{2n+1} \cap \big(\mathbb C^n \times [0,\infty)\big) = $ upper hemisphere of $S^{2n} \subset S^{2n+1}$. One could also denote it by $S^{2n}_+$, but Hatcher prefers $D^{2n}_+$ for mnemonical reasons.

Thank you for clarification!
